# Will cleaning out my provisioning profiles invalidate my app store submission?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I had the latest version of OSX installed on my computer yesterday and I've lost my previous keychains.  Now all the provisioning profiles result in the error that say "Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain."  The easiest solution is for me to delete the provisioning profiles, however I have an appstore submission that is using one of those distribution provisioning profiles.  Two questions:

1. Should I avoid deleting the app store submission provisioning profile?
2. If I can't delete this provisioning profile, that means I can't delete the existing certificates which tied to my old private key.  How can I create new provisioning profiles then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Technical Note from Apple will help you out I'm sure:
[Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933)

Especially the section "*Deleting/Revoking Your Certificates and Starting Fresh*" might be helpful to you.

Comment: Link is unfortunately broken since iOS 10 release